# Cross compiling boost libraries for power-pc fails

Tags: linux, gcc, boost, g++, cross-compiling

I need to cross compile the boost libraries for power-pc.

Please find below my steps I've performed to get it to run:

I've

1. downloaded boost 1.61
2. unpacked it under **/home/emh2**
3. and executed **sudo ./home/bootstrap.sh** to boost builder **b2**
4. Boost.Builder **b2** was successfully created.

The cross compiler **powerpc-bt-linux-gnuspe-g++** is located under the following path:

> /usr/local/cross/i686-bt-linux/usr/bin/powerpc-bt-linux-gnuspe/

The include directories for the cross-compiler are as follows

> /usr/local/cross/ppce500v2-bt-linux-gnuspe/usr/include/c++/5.2.0/powerpc-bt-linux-gnuspe
>
> /usr/local/cross/ppce500v2-bt-linux-gnuspe/usr/include/c++/5.2.0/
>
> /usr/local/cross/ppce500v2-bt-linux-gnuspe/usr/include/

Next I've created in **/home** the **user-config.jam** with the following content:

```
 using gcc 
 : ppc 
 : /usr/local/cross/i686-bt-linux/usr/bin/powerpc-bt-linux-gnuspe/powerpc-bt-linux-gnuspe-g++ 
 : <compilerflags>-I/usr/local/cross/ppce500v2-bt-linux-gnuspe/usr/include/c++/5.2.0/powerpc-bt-linux-gnuspe -I/usr/local/cross/ppce500v2-bt-linux-gnuspe/usr/include/c++/5.2.0/ -I/usr/local/cross/ppce500v2-bt-linux-gnuspe/usr/include/    ;
```

Afterwards I started the cross compilation with

> ./b2 toolset=gcc-ppc --with-log

And here is the output which indicates, that a file/directory cannot be found:

```
Performing configuration checks
- 32-bit                   : yes (cached)
- arm                      : no  (cached)
- mips1                    : no  (cached)
- power                    : yes (cached)

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.
- symlinks supported       : yes (cached)
- compiler-supports-visibility : yes (cached)
- has_icu builds           : no  (cached)
- lockfree boost::atomic_flag : no  (cached)
Component configuration:

- atomic                   : not building
- chrono                   : not building
- container                : not building
- context                  : not building
- coroutine                : not building
- coroutine2               : not building
- date_time                : not building
- exception                : not building
- filesystem               : not building
- graph                    : not building
- graph_parallel           : not building
- iostreams                : not building
- locale                   : not building
- log                      : building
- math                     : not building
- metaparse                : not building
- mpi                      : not building
- program_options          : not building
- python                   : not building
- random                   : not building
- regex                    : not building
- serialization            : not building
- signals                  : not building
- system                   : not building
- test                     : not building
- thread                   : not building
- timer                    : not building
- type_erasure             : not building
- wave                     : not building
...patience...
...patience...
...patience...
...patience...
...found 4056 targets...
...updating 208 targets...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/atomic/build/gcc-ppc/release/threading- multi/lockpool.o
libs/atomic/src/lockpool.cpp:15:19: fatal error: cstddef: No such file or   directory
compilation terminated.

"/usr/local/cross/i686-bt-linux/usr/bin/powerpc-bt-linux-gnuspe/powerpc-bt-linux-gnuspe-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline    -Wall -pthread -fPIC -m32  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_ATOMIC_DYN_LINK=1   -DBOOST_ATOMIC_SOURCE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/atomic/build/gcc-ppc   /release/threading-multi/lockpool.o" "libs/atomic/src/lockpool.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/atomic/build/gcc-ppc/release/threading-  multi/lockpool.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2/libs/atomic/build/gcc-ppc/release/threading-  multi>libboost_atomic.so.1.61.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs/atomic/build/gcc-ppc  /release/threading-multi>lockpool.o...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_atomic.so.1.61.0 for lack of <pbin.v2/libs /atomic/build/gcc-ppc/release/threading-multi>libboost_atomic.so.1.61.0...
...skipped <pstage/lib>libboost_atomic.so for lack of   <pstage/lib>libboost_atomic.so.1.61.0...
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/date_time/build/gcc-ppc/release/threading-  multi/gregorian/greg_month.o
In file included from ./boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp:12:0,
             from libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_month.cpp:14:
./boost/date_time/constrained_value.hpp:12:21: fatal error: exception: No    such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

What I'm missing here? Why do I get these "No such file or directory" errors?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would run

```
./b2 --debug-configuration -n
```

as described [here](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/configuration.html). This should allow you to confirm that b2 is grabbing the correct jam file. It looks for user-config.jam in /home/user/ so you may need to move it to that directory if it isn't there already.

Additionally, I've found myself needing to write out `<compileflag>-option1 <compileflag>-option2 etc...` There may be a way of pass a whole string of options but just spacing them apart after a single `<compileflags>` doesn't seem to work.

The output shows you the full compile command this is run. You should see your compile flags show up there and can use that to verify your jam file syntax is working properly.

In your output above, you can that your intended includes are not showing up

```
"/usr/local/cross/i686-bt-linux/usr/bin/powerpc-bt-linux-gnuspe/powerpc-bt-linux-gnuspe-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline    -Wall -pthread -fPIC -m32  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_ATOMIC_DYN_LINK=1   -DBOOST_ATOMIC_SOURCE -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/atomic/build/gcc-ppc   /release/threading-multi/lockpool.o" "libs/atomic/src/lockpool.cpp"
```